# how to get the value from placepicker while selecting on suggestion

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, gmsplacepicker

I am getting stuck on this i want to get alert the whole value when user click with mouse suppose now i enter perston here when i click on first suggestion then it alert only perston. I don't know what i am doing wrong here is the screenshot. I want whole value in alert box but when i do with down arrow key and select first sugggestion and  press tab it gives me right value in alert box.
[image]

Here is my jquery Code:-

```
var location ="";
    $(document).on('change','#locationsearch',function(){
        location = $("#locationsearch").val();
        alert(location); return false;
    });
```

Thanks in advance. Helpful link must commented

Answer (score 0):

To get selected text, you should use

`$("select option:selected").text();`

If you have the value of the selected option, you can use this too:

`$("#SELECT_ID option[value=VALUE]").text();`

Comment: no this is no right i have textbox not select i am using placepicker

Comment: In case of textbox, you can directly use `$("TEXTBOX_ID").val()`. This would give you the value present in that textbox.

Comment: plz see my question i have also  used same

Comment: Can you share the HTML code as well, to better understand the problem.

Comment: <input type="text" id="locationsearch" class="form-control txtfield m-tb-10 placepicker" placeholder="Enter Location">